# Why is gcc destroying my object instantly despite its scope? (and how do I make it not do that?)

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc, destructor, raii

I wrote a small profiling class with an accompanying guard class to use like this:

```
{
    ProfileGuard pg("SampleName");

    // Code to profile
    ...
}
```

But then I noticed that sometimes gcc optimizes the code so that `pg` is destructed instantly. Apparently it detects that `pg` and the other code will not influence eachother. What's the best way to prevent gcc from doing this?

**Update:**
Since there is some serious disbelief concerning my question I will check my code again. I based my question on:

3.7.3 3.

> If a variable with automatic storage duration has initialization or a destructor with side effects, it shall not
>    be destroyed before the end of its block, nor shall it be eliminated as an optimization even if it appears to
>   be unused, except that a class object or its copy/move may be eliminated as specified in 12.8.

Is doing a print a "side effect"?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent it?

Comment: I don't buy this. Yes, maybe gcc eliminates both construction and destruction, but I don't believe it changes their timing. Could you post code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Never seen that.  Could it be possible that your initialisation is more complex and you got hit by the [tag:most-vexing-parse]?

Comment: @Beta: Obviously he wants that code for some debugging/profiling and obviously gcc optimizing code away breaks his debugging/profiling.

Comment: @Beta -- The constructed object may hold a lock that is needed for the block.  This is a common style of coding, and if the compiler broke it lots of code would be broken.

Comment: Don't profile that way! :) There's a better way. Take stack samples at random wall-clock time, the way [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/) does. (And you don't need a lot of samples.) Then for each line of code that appears, tell what percent of samples contain it. If there's anything you can fix to speed things up, *it's in that list*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Apparently it detects that pg and the other code will not influence eachother.

How, since that’s patently untrue? They *do* influence each other (e.g. through output order).

GCC doesn’t do this. Perhaps you accidentally used an anonymous (and hence temporary) object?

```
ProfileGuard("SampleName");
```

Now, this *will* be destructed immediately after executing the expression.

Comment: I'm a little bit ashamed but `ProfileGuard("SampleName");` is exactly what happened :)

Comment: I ran into the very same problem. Debugged it for like 5 hours. Then I found this. Exactly the same mistake. Haha. How ignorant of me!